# How can I get the word2vec.bin file

Tags: nlp, chatbot, word2vec, word-embedding, seq2seq

I want to build a chatbot using python and deeplearning methodology.Iam referring the below link
[chatbot code](https://github.com/shreyans29/thesemicolon/blob/master/chatbotPreprocessing.py)
But I troubled in the word2vec.bin file as describing in the code.Where should I get the bin file?

Comment: Please post your code on here instead of externally

Comment: Thanks and I got the word2vec.bin file from the given link                                                     https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec